# Loading Flash when debugging AIR

Tags: javascript, air, adobe, flash

I'm trying to create an **Adobe AIR widget** with a *Flash* menu.

The Flash menu was created in **SWiSH Max2**, exported as **SWF9** with **SWF6** properties exposed.
The menu works, FSCommand works, and the attached JavaScript work (at least in Firefox).

However, when I try to test this in the AIR Debug Launcher (ADL), nothing happens.

I've used **SWFObject**, and nothing happens.  I've hard-coded the OBJECT tag, and the best I get is a blank area the size of my Flash object.

I've checked the **adl.exe commandline arguments** and done my best so that it starts locally within the widgets *root-dir*, but I still get nothing.

Am I missing some specific way to load Flash into an AIR app?  (This would not surprise me, as I am a Flash/SWiSH newbie.)

Comment: To some degree.  Ideally...depending on how WebKit likes FSCommand...I'd like the Flash menu to drive JavaScript code.

Comment: I've never build and AIR app that uses HTML/JS, I've used actionscript only so far. Try using External Interface instead of FSCommand. It's a bit annoying to setup, but once you're there it works. Use the Example code in the documentation to get started. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html. Hope it helps